# Getting started with Powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

I am just getting started with a basic tutorial to Sharepoint and Powershell, following the following commands while in Powershell on my SP server:

```
[system.reflection.assembly]:loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Sharepoint")
$siteurl="http://localhost"
$mysite = new-object Microsoft.sharepoint.SPSite($site)
$mysite.gettype()
```

Up to here works fine, I get a response from gettype  But $mysite.Allwebs does not have anything.

```
$mysite.Allwebs.count
```

Does not even show zero.  So it looks like I a missing some important piece.  Any ideas?

Thank you.
Daniel Williams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags indicate that you're working with SharePoint 2010 but your PSH looks like you're working with SharePoint 2007.

If you're working with SPT 2010, there are about 500 custom PSH cmdlets.

As for the code you have, try this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | Out-Null

$site = New-Object -typename "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite" -argumentlist "http://localhost"
```

The `out-null` just throws the output away that otherwise goes to the console (in case you're wondering).

Comment: That worked, thank you.  What part of my script looks like SP 2007?

Comment: All the stuff you're doing getting the Microsoft.SharePoint namespace is stuff I have to do when working with SPT 2007. It's not necessary in SPT 2010 as there's a PSH module that you load up using `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell`. You then write something like `Get-SPSite -Identity http://localhost` The [Microsoft Scripting Guys](http://technet.com/scriptcenter) have some good stuff on using them.

Comment: aha, just found that add  in. very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a good grasp not only of Powershell for SharePoint, but of the basics of powershell as well, i suggest you get this book: [PowerShell for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administrators](http://sharepointandpowershell.com/). It offers excellent examples and step by step explanation of how to work with sharepoint using Powershell.

Also, if you want to see some really hardcore Powershell for sharepoint, I suggest downloading [SPAutoinstaller](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/), which performs a complete sharepoint install and touches pretty much every admin ps concept there is for sharepoint.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I was looking at books, and saw this one.  Your endorsement is a positive.

Comment: Great book, I bought that one to help me out and its a great starting point but if you have been doing this awhile it's going ot be a bit basic.